# Adb am command work, but the intent in java code dont work

Tags: java, android, android-intent, adb

sorry for my english, and need a little help

im bulding an app, and this app need to import a ovpn file to the openvpn connect app.

im run this command from adb and work fine

```
    adb shell am start -n net.openvpn.openvpn/.OpenVPNAttachmentReceiver -a         android.intent.action.VIEW -d "/MyPcHardDis/profile.ovpn" -t "application/x-openvpn-profile"
```

but if im building an intent to launch the same command

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("android.intent.action.VIEW");
    intent.setComponent(new   ComponentName("net.openvpn.openvpn","net.openvpn.openvpn.OpenVPNAttachmentReceiver"));
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("/storage/emulated/0/Download/asdf.ovpn"));
    intent.setType("application/x-openvpn-profile");
    startActivity(intent);
```

after launch, the openvpn app open but doesnt import the profile.

the intent is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("android.intent.action.VIEW");
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("net.openvpn.openvpn","net.openvpn.openvpn.OpenVPNAttachmentReceiver"));
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(file_path), "application/x-openvpn-profile");
        startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/) with the [startapp plugin](https://github.com/lampaa/com.lampa.startapp) you can do this:

```
navigator.startApp.start([
  ["net.openvpn.openvpn","net.openvpn.openvpn.OpenVPNAttachmentReceiver"],
  ["cdvfile://localhost/persistent/Download/asdf.ovpn"]
], function(message) {
  /* success */
}, 
function(error) {
  /* error */
});
```